In the Lorentz oscillator model, what does it mean if the high-frequency dielectric constant for a material is negative?
The high-frequency dielectric constant ε_∞ is supposed to account for all the absorption modes outside the measured frequency range. What does it mean if it's negative? Is it unphysical?

Well, what would that mean for propagation at those high frequencies?

One way to think about this is two consider two Lorentz oscillators, but with one with a resonance at very high frequency while setting eps_infty = 0. If I remember correctly you can adjust parameters of the higher mode and look at its lower freq limit to understand eps_infty

A simple way to think about this is to set $\epsilon_{\infty}=0$ and thinkabout this as a system with two resonances, one at a frequency within your measurement range, and another which is at much higher frequency.
Then, you can represent your system in terms of two Lorentz Oscillators
$\epsilon(\omega) = 1+ \frac{s_0}{\omega_{0}^2 - \omega^2 - i \Gamma_0 \omega} + \frac{s_1}{\omega_{1}^2 - \omega^2 - i \Gamma_1 \omega}$
Where $\omega_1 \gg \omega_0$. Then, you can look at the last term in the limit of $\omega \ll \omega_1$ and see that it gives a negative contribution to $\text{Re}[\epsilon]$ (see plot of the Lorentz model below). So effectively, you have a negative $\epsilon_{\infty}$. This observation provides an answer to your question, a negative value for $\epsilon_{\infty}$ could indicate the presence of a resonance at higher frequency than your measurement window.
You can also have the reverse happen as well, where you are measuring the dielectric function in a certain region and see a positive $\epsilon_{\infty}$ due to a resonance well below the frequency of study. In many materials, there are many resonances across the frequency spectrum, making things messy in general.

